# Shapefile with overlapping polygons: calculate average values

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.0, shapefile, polygon, ogr

I have a very big polygon shapefile with hundreds of features, often overlapping each other. Each of these features has a value stored in the attribute table. I simply need to calculate the average values in the areas where they overlap. I can imagine that this task requires several intricate steps: I was wondering if there is a straightforward methodology. I’m open to every kind of suggestion, I can use ArcMap, QGis, arcpy scripts, PostGis, GDAL… I just need ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Union tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000s000000) from ArcGIS. It will create new polygons where the polygons overlap. In order to keep the attributes from both polygons, add your polygon shapefile twice as input and use ALL as join_attributes parameter.This creates also polygons intersecting with themselves, you can select and delete them easily as they have the same FIDs. Then just add a new field to the attribute table and calculate it based on the two original value fields from the input polygons. This can be done in a script or directly with the toolbox's tools.

Answer (score 1):

After few attempts, I found a solution by rasterising all the features singularly and then performing cell statistics in order to calculate the average. See below the script I wrote, please do not hesitate to comment and improve it! 
Thanks!

```
#This script processes a shapefile of snow persistence (area of interest: Afghanistan).
#the input shapefile represents a month of snow cover and contains several features.
#each feature represents a particular day and a particular snow persistence (low,medium,high,nodata)
#these features are polygons multiparts, often overlapping.
#a feature of a particular day can overlap a feature of another one, but features of the same day and with
#different snow persistence can not overlap each other.
#(potentially, each shapefile contains 31*4 feature).
#the script takes the features singularly and exports each feature in a temporary shapefile
#which contains only one feature.
#Then, each feature is converted to raster, and after
#a logical conditional expression gives a value to the pixel according the intensity (high=3,medium=2,low=1,nodata=skipped).
#Finally, all these rasters are summed and divided by the number of days, in order to
#calculate an average value.
#The result is a raster with the average snow persistence in a particular month.
#This output raster ranges from 0 (no snow) to 3 (persistent snow for the whole month)
#and values outside this range should be considered as small errors in pixel overlapping.
#This script needs a particular folder structure. The folder C:\TEMP\Afgh_snow_cover contains 3 subfolders
#input, temp and outputs. The script takes care automatically of the cleaning of temporary data


import arcpy, numpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env

#function for finding unique values of a field in a FC
def unique_values_in_table(table, field):
        data = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(table, [field])
        return numpy.unique(data[field])

#check extensions
try:
    if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    else:
        # Raise a custom exception
        #
        raise LicenseError
except LicenseError:
    print "spatial Analyst license is unavailable"  
except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages(2)
finally:
    # Check in the 3D Analyst extension
    #
    arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")

# parameters and environment
temp_folder = r"C:\TEMP\Afgh_snow_cover\temp_rasters"
output_folder = r"C:\TEMP\Afgh_snow_cover\output_rasters"
env.workspace = temp_folder
unique_field = "FID"
field_Date = "DATE"
field_Type = "Type"
cellSize = 0.02


fc = r"C:\TEMP\Afgh_snow_cover\input_shapefiles\snow_cover_Dec2007.shp"

stat_output_name = fc[-11:-4] + ".tif"

#print stat_output_name
arcpy.env.extent = "MAXOF"

#find all the uniquesID of the FC
uniqueIDs = unique_values_in_table(fc, "FID")

#make layer for selecting
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (fc, "lyr")
#uniqueIDs = uniqueIDs[-5:]
totFeatures = len(uniqueIDs)
#for each feature, get the date and the type of snow persistence(type can be high, medium, low and nodata)
for i in uniqueIDs:
    SC = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
    for row in SC:
        if row.getValue(unique_field) == i:
            datestring = row.getValue(field_Date)
            typestring = row.getValue(field_Type)

    month = str(datestring.month)
    day = str(datestring.day)
    year = str(datestring.year)

#format month and year string
    if len(month) == 1:
        month = '0' + month

    if len(day) == 1:
        day = '0' + day

#convert snow persistence to numerical value
    if typestring == 'high':
        typestring2 = 3
    if typestring == 'medium':
        typestring2 = 2
    if typestring == 'low':
        typestring2 = 1
    if typestring == 'nodata':
        typestring2 = 0
#skip the NoData features, and repeat the following for each feature (a feature is a day and a persistence value)
    if typestring2 > 0:
            #create expression for selecting the feature
            expression = ' "FID" = ' + str(i) + ' '
            #select the feature
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
            #create 
            #outFeatureClass = os.path.join(temp_folder, ("M_Y_" + str(i)))
            #create faeture class name, writing the snow persistence value at the end of the name
            outFeatureClass = "Afg_" + str(year) + str(month) + str(day) + "_" + str(typestring2) + '.shp'
            #export the feature
            arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("lyr", temp_folder, outFeatureClass)
            print "exported FID " + str(i) + " \ " + str(totFeatures)
            #create name of the raster and convert the newly created feature to raster
            outRaster = outFeatureClass[4:-4] + ".tif"
            arcpy.FeatureToRaster_conversion(outFeatureClass, field_Type, outRaster, cellSize)
            #remove the temporary fc
            arcpy.Delete_management(outFeatureClass)
    del SC, row
#now many rasters are created, representing the snow persistence types of each day. 
#list all the rasters created 
rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "All")
print rasterList

#now the rasters have values 1 and 0. the following loop will
#perform CON expressions in order to assign the value of snow persistence
for i in rasterList:
        print i + ":"
        inRaster = Raster(i)
        #set the value of snow persistence, stored in the raster name
        value_to_set = i[-5]
        inTrueRaster = int(value_to_set)
        inFalseConstant = 0
        whereClause = "Value > 0"


        # Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
        print 'Executing CON expression and deleting input'
        # Execute Con , in order to assign to each pixel the value of snow persistence
        print str(inTrueRaster)
        try:
                outCon = Con(inRaster, inTrueRaster, inFalseConstant, whereClause)
        except:
                print 'CON expression failed (probably empty raster!)'

        nameoutput = i[:-4] + "_c.tif"
        outCon.save(nameoutput)
        #delete the temp rasters with values 0 and 1
        arcpy.Delete_management(i)
#list the raster with values of snow persistence
rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters("*_c.tif", "All")
#sum the rasters
print "Caclulating SUM"
outCellStats = CellStatistics(rasterList, "SUM", "DATA")
#calculate the number of days (num of rasters/3)
print "Calculating day ratio"
num_of_rasters = len(rasterList)
print 'Num of rasters : ' + str(num_of_rasters)
num_of_days = num_of_rasters / 3
print 'Num of days : ' + str(num_of_days)
#in order to store decimal values, multiplicate the raster by 1000 before dividing
outCellStats = outCellStats * 1000 / num_of_days
#save the output raster
print "saving output " + stat_output_name
stat_output_name = os.path.join(output_folder,stat_output_name)
outCellStats.save(stat_output_name)
#delete the remaining temporary rasters
print "deleting CON rasters"
for i in rasterList:
        print "deleting " + i
        arcpy.Delete_management(i)
arcpy.Delete_management("lyr")
```

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS :

1) "feature to polygon" to create new polygons where you have some overlaps

2) "feature to point" (with inside option) to create the centroids of the new polygons

3) "spatial join" (JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE option) between the points and the original polygons (to have the mean values of the attributes of your original polygons)

4) "spatial join" or table join between your points and the non overlapping polygon to conclude

Comment: Thanks! 
I agree, this is the usual methodology for making a 'heat map', I have already done that way in the past and it perfectly works. 
Unfortunately, this time the size of the shapefiles I'm dealing with is too big, and I can't run tools like "Feature to Polygon'. 

I'm thinking about two possible workarounds: 

1) Simplify these polygons (ether with ogr2ogr or with PostGis), and then repeat the classing heat map methodology.
2) Convert everything to raster, by creating a raster for each feature, then proceeding with raster algebra...

Comment: Have you tried using a geodatabase instead of a shapefile. I've just done something similar with thousands of polygon today.